# How to send email when save method is triggered in django admin panel

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-admin

I have used the default Django admin panel as my backend. I have a Blogpost model. What I am trying to do is whenever an admin user saves a blogpost object on Django admin, I need to send an email to the newsletter subscribers notifying them that there is a new blog on the website.

Since Django admin automatically saves the blog by calling the save function, I don't know where to write send email api logic. Hope I have explained it well.

My Blogpost:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):

    author = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Admin')
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('travel_news', 'Travel News',),
        ('travel_tips', 'Travel Tips',),
        ('things_to_do', 'Things to Do',),
        ('places_to_go', 'Places to Go'),
    )
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='travel_news')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()

    # todo support for tags
    # tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='travel') #todo
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    date_created = models.DateField()
```

I have overwritten the Django admin form by my model form like this.

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('travel_news', 'Travel News',),
        ('travel_tips', 'Travel Tips',),
        ('things_to_do', 'Things to Do',),
        ('places_to_go', 'Places to Go'),
    )
    # categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['author','image', 'title','categories',
                  'caption','content','tag','date_created']

@register(BlogPost)
class BlogPostAdmin(ModelAdmin):


    # autocomplete_fields = ['author']
    def edit(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a class="btn-btn" href="/admin/blogs/blogpost/{}/change/">Change</a>', obj.id)

    def delete(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a class="btn-btn" href="/admin/blogs/blogpost/{}/delete/">Delete</a>', obj.id)

    list_display = ('categories', 'title', 'date_created','edit', 'delete')
    icon_name = 'chrome_reader_mode'
    # inlines = [TagInline]
    form = BlogForm
```

I have written a view, but it doesnt make sense since there is no any url calling it as we dont need any view and url when saving from the django admin itself.

```
from apps.blogs.admin import BlogForm
def blogform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Without this logic too, the form is working fine.

My subscribers model:

```
class Subscribers(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_subscribed = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Newsletter Subscribers"
```

Comment: What about to [override `save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) blog method? Or just to [bind to post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) ?

Comment: Ok but where to write the post save signal call?? and also where to write the logic after the signal is sent??

Comment: I can write an answer based on signal if it is a solution for your issue.

Comment: sure. I will try to implement it. @daniherrera

Comment: I just posted a sample with all elements: blog, blogpost, signal, send_mail, subscribers, ...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can send and email to subscribers after a new `Post` is created:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User) # <-- subscribers
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete= models.CASCADE) #<-- blog
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # ....

# binding sinal:
@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def send_mail_to_subs(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if Not created:
        return
        
    for mysub in instance.blog.subscribers.all():
        send_mail(
            f'New Post {instance.title}',
            'Hi .... ',
            'from@example.com',
            [sub.email],
        )
```

Be free to adapt this sample to your custom scenario. For example, maybe do you have other relations to get blog or subscribers.

#### About performance.

If do you have lots of subscribers, this is not a real solution. For massive mailing do you need a background process to send mails.

For example, you can add a field to store if a post was notified to subscribers:

```py
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete= models.CASCADE) #<-- blog
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notified = models.BooleanField(editable=False, default=False)
```

Then execute a process each X minutes to get not notified posts and send mails to all subscribers.

Do you have two options:

- [Custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) on system cron
- [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: Wont it be slow, if emails are sent using for loop if there are like 1000 emails?? @dani

Comment: Also, I have a separate model named Subscribers which contains fields email and date_subscribed.

Comment: These two comments contain relevant information I miss in your initial question. I modified my answer to match with this new constraints.

Comment: Hello @dani, newsletter feature was added latest on the backend. Blogpost model was already created a long time ago and now there are many clients data on it. I have updated my above code with the subscribers model. Now I need to pick users from that model. How to do that istead of adding user field to Blogpost model??

Comment: Hi @Django-Rocks, for me this Q is already answered. If you have new requirements be free to post new Qs :) Regards!

Comment: hey @dani can you help me on this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426185/function-call-in-another-file-not-working-in-django-rest-framework/68429016#68429016

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `save` method in your model.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Admin')
    .....
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.pk:
             # send mail here
              send_mail()
         return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can write the signals also.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def send_mail_to_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       # send mail
         send_mail()
```

Comment: Hey @Arjun can you help me on this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426185/function-call-in-another-file-not-working-in-django-rest-framework/68429016#68429016

Answer (score 0):

Better to use signals. If you need to send it to all subscribers you need to create a loop in signal function.

You can create a signal in blog post view like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def send_mail_to_subs(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for subs in instance.author.subscribed.all():
            send_mail(
                f'New Post from {instance.author}',
                f'Title: {instance.post_title}',
                'youremail',
                [subs.email],
            )
```

Good coding :)